# How to filter records based on a criteria per group

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL how can I express this question: For all groups, return all records in a group that match the result of a condition specific to the group.

For example:

```
Book: (Id, Title, AuthorName, PublishDate)
```

Return all records in `Book` table that if the books are grouped by the `AuthorName`, they are the fifth or later books of that specific author.

I'm using MS SQL Server 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this is basically the same as [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6841605/2029983), however, instead of `= 1` you want `>=5`:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT {Columns}
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Author ORDER By PublishDate) AS RN
    FROM dbo.YourTable)
SELECT {Columns
FROM CTE
WHERE RN >= 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a correlated subquery for this:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.publishdate >= (select t2.publishdate
                        from t t2
                        where t2.author = t.author 
                        order by t2.publishdate asc
                        offset 4 fetch first 1 row only
                       );
```